# efficient 3D interpolation/approximation in scipy (python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, approximation

Below is small example code which tries to interpolate EEG cap signals. In the example, EEG cap has 44 channels/electrodes, and 1125 timestamps for each of the channels. Furthermore there are 800 samples which contain 1125 timestamps of 44 channels/electrodes each.

I tried RBF interpolation from scipy but it seems to be very slow.

Please note that the electrode coordinates only needed to be rotated once.

How can I improve the code such that interpolation is faster? I am open to consider other interpolation/approximation method.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

x = np.random.rand(44,1)
y = np.random.rand(44,1)
z = np.random.rand(44,1)

xR = np.random.rand(44,1)
yR = np.random.rand(44,1)
zR = np.random.rand(44,1)

time_series = np.random.rand(800,44,1125)
time_series_rotated = np.zeros((800,44,1125))

total_time_steps = time_series.shape[2]
total_samples = time_series.shape[0]

for s in range(total_samples):
  for t in range(total_time_steps):
    rbfi = Rbf(x, y, z, time_series[s,:,t], function="quintic")
    time_series_rotated[s,:,t] = np.squeeze(rbfi(xR, yR, zR))
```

Answer (score 0):

`griddata` accept multidimensional arrays as values, so you can directly write:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

nbr_electrodes = 44
nbr_samples = 800
nbr_timestamps = 125  # to be testable

xyz = np.random.rand(nbr_electrodes, 3)
xyz_rotated = np.random.rand(nbr_electrodes, 3)
time_series = np.random.rand(nbr_electrodes, nbr_timestamps, nbr_samples)

time_series_rotated = griddata(xyz, time_series, xyz_rotated, method='linear')
```

Note that the points (electrodes) are on the first dimension now. It takes less than 100 ms on my computer versus more than 1s for the loop method.

`time_series_rotated.shape` gives `(44, 125, 800)`